# How can I force sync mode on dynatree?

Tags: ajax, synchronous, dynatree

I'm using Martin Wendt's [Dynatree](http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/) and want to update the tree in Ajax, dynamically and recursively.

For this, I'm using functions like `tree.getNodeByKey(nodes[i-1]).appendAjax({});`
and `tree.activateKey(nodes[i]);` in a `for` loop.

When adding `alert("Hello world");` into the loop, my code works correctly 95% or the time.  Without it, the code never works.

The problem is obviously coming from the fact that **Dynatree is performing its Ajax requests in asynchronous mode**, and seem ignoring the `async:false`, when added to `.initAjax` and/or `.appendAjax`:

```
        jQuery('#tree').dynatree("getTree").getNodeByKey(nodes[i-1]).appendAjax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "inc/treeNodes.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {key: nodes[i]},
        async:false
        });
```

I tried adding `setTimeout (function() {},2000);` around the call to `.appendAjax`, but it prevented this method to work.

Could Dynatree be modified to support asynchronous mode?

Answer (score 0):

Although it does not truly answer the question of running Dynatree in synchronous mode, I found a **workaround** that almost emulates an Ajax synchronous behavior.

Edit: the following workaround seems working reasonably well on localhost, but not if the site is remote.

---

Before important calls to Dynatree's method, add a setTimeOut() call at the end of which something will be written to the console.

```
   for (i=1; i < n; i++) {
        (...)
        setTimeout(function(){console.log('_')}, 3000);  
        jQuery('#tree').dynatree("getTree").getNodeByKey(nodes[i-1]).appendAjax({...});
        (...)
    }
```

The `setTimeout` does not slower the code as much as the delay would suggest.
For instance, if the loop has three iterations, you don't have to wait 9 seconds (3x 3000) before the work done by all three appendAjax calls complete.
I assume that `.appendAjax()` calls are performed whilst `setTimeout` is still running, but the later seem having some magic effect on the document window.

Using `setTimeout` and trigger `console.log()` has similar effect as inserting `alert();` calls, but is "silent" for the visitor.

Comment: Note: putting the jQuery stuff inside the function triggered by setTimeout would not work.